# Fastest way to search list for second-to-last not-None item

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, search

Here is my Python algorithm:

```
def secondToLastNotNone(list_):
    foundLastNotNone = False
    for v in reversed(list_):
        if v is not None:
            if foundLastNotNone:
                return v
            foundLastNotNone = True
    raise ValueError("No not-None values")
```

```
secondToLastNotNone([None, None, 1, 2, 3, 4, None, 5, None, None])
# Output: 4
```

I'm using this algorithm in some big-data operation.
Is there any way to improve this algorithm for speed?

I've tried other ways to do this (more concise and readable) but this is the best I've found so far, still it's kinda slow.

The items need to be in a list, not a set, as there may be duplicates and their order matters.

The possible values of each item in the list are either `None` or a float.

Comment: I wouldn’t reverse it and just iterate with a range and a negative step to avoid having the reverse the list at all

Comment: @Sayse - `reversed` is an iterator (like `range`) not a new list. Indexing from `range`  indices is almost always a bad idea in python.

Comment: @Sayse I tried that but it's even slower than reversed(), keep in mind that reversed gives an iterator so it's not going to generate the whole reversed list unless it needs to.

Comment: @RedKnight91 - That's because indexing into a list is slower than iterating. Your solution 
is already very efficient.

Comment: I think you should use `if v is not None:` rather than inequality.

Comment: @balmy I've actually already corrected that to ```if v:```

Comment: Hmm, an empty string, empty list, 0 and False, and None, are false truthy-wise, but _not_ all the same as None. Check your data to make sure your `if v:` is the right thing to do. If the title of your question were ‘second to last Truthy-True item’ then I’d agree with you; maybe you need to change the title of your question?

Comment: (If this was a "3rd party problem": Sure it isn't about a *linked list*?)